# Div float issue on parent div

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have lots of divs inside a container and I want to align them left or right,

The problem is that when two or more divs are same class="left" instead all of them to go left, the second one sits next to the other div as it has space. Also when one is "left" end other is "right" there yes they may stay side by side.

Here is an example: http://www.bookingmallorca.co.uk/arq/prueba.html

The blue div is a div from side to side of parent, that's OK
the grey div must float left and the red right, as you may see there is one gray not well aligned as there are

So what I need is something to show different float side divs next to each other like on that example and same float value always to float at that float value

Comment: What happens if you try adding `clear:both` to `pau`?

Comment: I'm finding it quite hard to understand what you want. You say that you want the grey div to float left and the red div to float right, yet partway down the example you have that exactly.

Comment: yes i understan but my divs are php auto created so this is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by introducing **2 additional .left and .right float div** like below.

***Important:*** remove existing float properties of the classes

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="hola">
  <div class="left">
     <div class="pau"></div>
     <div class="losdos"></div>
     <div class="gerardo"></div>
     <div class="losdos"></div>
     <div class="pau"></div>
     <div class="gerardo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="gerardo"></div>
    <div class="pau"></div>
    <div class="pau"></div>
    <div class="pau"></div>
    <div class="gerardo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.hola {
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 250px;
}
.hola .pau {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #AFAFAF;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
}
.hola .losdos {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5FC9F0;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
}
.hola .gerardo {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F58787;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
}
.hola .left{
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
}
.hola .right{
    float: right;
    width: 125px;
}
```

​
You can find **working copy** on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xE3zw/)

Comment: yes i understan but my divs are php auto created so this is not an option . The problem with clear:both; is that when 2 divs are one "gerardo" and one "pau" they dont stay besides.

Comment: OK sure.Then please update your answer and accept it as answer and add new tag also as php. If this is a php question then I never answered this.B'cos I am not a php guy.After you update your answer I will remove my Answer.Thanks.

Comment: @user1855206 That the server side code is PHP here should have nothing to do with the validity of this answer. PHP generates HTML. Just take this code and adapt it.